# Como criar uma view em um projeto Django com Python? Estou tendo erros

Tags: python-3.x, django, fullcalendar

Sou iniciante em Django.

Estou dando continuidade a um projeto pronto feito em Django. Estou querendo adicionar uma agenda ao projeto usando Full Calendar.

Para isso já desenvolvi o template com o arquivo html, adicionei o arquivo css e js no static, da mesma maneira que é feita no restante do projeto.

Para abrir essa agenda, na barra de menu lateral que exite no meu projeto, dentro de templates, no arquivo base para todas as telas, faço assim:

```
<li>
     <a href="{% url 'agenda:agendaview' %}">
          <i class="material-icons">&#xE878;</i>
          <span>Agenda</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

No meu arquivo settings.py acrescentei o app agenda:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'djangosige.apps.agenda',
]
```

O meu arquivo agenda.html, dentro de templates > agenda está assim:

```
{%extends 'base/base.html'%}

{%block title%}Agenda{%endblock%}
{%block content%}

<div id='calendar'></div>

{%endblock%}
```

Dentro da pasta apps, criei uma pasta agenda, no arquivo urls.py fiz isso:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

from djangosige.configs import DEBUG

app_name = 'agenda'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='agendaview'),
    ]

if DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
         url(r'^404/$', views.handler404),
         url(r'^500/$', views.handler500),
    ]
```

Agora preciso criar o arquivo view, mas não estou sabendo como, já fiz várias pesquisas mas não consegui entender.

Resumindo, eu tenho uma barra lateral com várias opções (cadastros, estoque) e estou querendo adicionar uma agenda, essa agenda já está funcionando quando a insiro na página inicial do programa, agora quero criar uma opção agenda somente para ela. Com os arquivos que eu já criei estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
'agenda' is not a registered namespace
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?